# Concatenating labelled array of arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to be able to achieve an array that will concatenate a user's tweets together with their label something like this

```
train = [
(['hurt','pain','shock'],'depressed'),
(['cut','harm','anxious'],'depressed'),
(['hurt','tears','stab'],'depressed'),
(['joy','smile','neutral'],'not'),
(['relax','enjoy','laugh'],'not'),
]
```

and I tried doing that by extending them into the array where alltweets contain all of the tweets the user has and cleantweets being the tweets after processing which will be used for the training.

```
    while i < len(alltweets) or len(alltweets) < 0:
        try:
            if (not alltweets[i].retweeted) and ('RT @' not in alltweets[i].text) and ('\ufe0f' not in alltweets[i].text):
                print("cleaning depressed:"+ p.clean(alltweets[i].text))
                cleantweets.append(p.clean(alltweets[i].text))

            i+=1
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            i+=1
            pass
    print (cleantweets)
    train.extend((cleantweets,'depressed'))
    print ("TRAINING")
    print (train)
    x+=1
```

But it only unfortunately gives something like this where the tweets and their aren't separated by user but instead just inserted into the array .

```
     train = [['dfasdf','asdfasdf','asdfasdf'],'depressed',['asdf','asdfasdf','adsfad,'],'depressed'

]
```

I've tried brute forcing by manually appending the '(' and ')' but it doesn't work.

Comment: What are the contents of alltweets?

Comment: You could probably be a little more clear regarding what your input is and what the output you want is given your input. Imagine if I asked "I want a function that returns something like 8, but it instead returns 22." That gives you no hints regarding what I actually want the function to do. As it stands right now we have to read your code in an attempt to guess what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to append, not extend:

```
x = []
x.append((['a', 'b'], 'depressed'))
print(x)
[(['a', 'b'], 'depressed')]
```

Extend adds each item *in* an iterable to the collection. Append adds whatever you specify to the collection.

Because your tuple was iterable, it added its values to the list instead of adding the tuple itself to the list.